# React NativeでFirebaseの型定義をする方法

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

React NativeでAndroidアプリの開発をしています。そのプロジェクトでFirebaseを使いたいので@types/react-native-firebaseの型定義パッケージをインストールようとしたのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

npmレジストリに存在しないせいだと思うのですが、この場合どのようにして型定義をすればよいか教えていただけないしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

インストールのコマンド

```
npm install @types/react-native-firebase --save-dev
```

エラー

```
C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactProject\ProjectName>npm install @types/react-native-firebase --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-native-firebase - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-native-firebase@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-03T02_53_04_589Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私自身は React Native を触ったことが無いので今回調べた程度ですが、実行すべきコマンドが違っていたりしませんか？

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app-types

> ```
> npm i @react-native-firebase/app-types
> ```

https://rnfirebase.io/

> ```
> # Using npm
> npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
> ```